# not able call more than one roles by using include_role

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

needed help to see what is wrong with this include_role.

This work without any problem:

```
#US East (N. Virginia)
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    region_services:
      - "us-east-1"
  tasks:
    - name: 3 run - should loop and print dynamic var
      include_role: name=nginx
      when: aws_region_name == "us-east-1"
      with_items:
        - "{{ region_services }}"
```

This doesn't work by calling any extra roles:

```
#US East (N. Virginia)
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    region_services:
      - "us-east-1"
  tasks:
    - name: 3 run - should loop and print dynamic var
      include_role: name=nginx
    - name: 4 run - should loop and print dynamic var
      include_role: name=nginx
      when: aws_region_name == "us-east-1"
      with_items:
        - "{{ region_services }}"
```

error I get like this

> 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in

Comment: I suspect you rely on `item` variable inside nginx role, so playbook fails because there is no `with_items` for the first `include_role` in the second code snippet.

Comment: thanks for the help!!!....I need with_items(item) values should be passed to all roles as the aws region is same for all the roles and unfortunately including with_items: for every roles is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also include roles in your playbook like this.

```
# US East (N. Virginia)
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    region_services:
      - "us-east-1"
  roles:  
    - {role: ../roles/nginx}
    - {role: ../roles/other}
  ...
```

Comment: grizzthedj@ getting error like this: "ERROR! 'when' is not a valid attribute for a Play"
  - hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: yes
    vars:
      region_services:
        - "us-east-1"
    roles:
      - { role: nginx }
      - { role: nginx }
    when: region_services == "us-east-1"
    with_items:
      - "{{ region_services }}"